# How to use baked fluid with network render?

Tags: rendering, network

I would like to use blender net render feature, but I know, that currently it does not support baking fluid simulations (see [Blender Netrender Manual](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Performance/Netrender)).

Is it possible to bake it locally and then use it in network rendering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but all the networked machines will need access to the cache.

Another way to do a network render:

- All machines need access to the blendfile and any external data (textures, fluid sim caches, etc.)
- Make all the machines output the rendered images to a shared directory
- Disable *Overwrite* in *Render Settings > Output* for all machines.
  The *Overwrite* option will overwrite existing image files in the output directory. Disabling it causes blender to skip rendering the frame if a corresponding file already exists.
- Enable *Placeholders* in *Render settings > Output* for all machines.
  When rendering is started on a new frame, if the *Placeholders* option is enabled, blender will create an empty file where the final output image will be written after the render is complete.

Then:

1. Open the blendfile on the first machine and start the render
2. Open the blendfile on the second machine and start the render

Each machine will output images to the shared output directory and skip already rendered frames because *Overwrite* is disabled.

*Placeholders* is enabled so that machines will skip rendering frames that other machines are working on at the same time.

Comment: no problem. should I set up path to that cache somewhere? should I set up the same *Path* for CLient, Master and Slave in Network render settings?

Comment: @betatester07 you would need to setup a shared file system easy when using linux but no idea how to do that on windows.

Comment: @betatester07 I'm not entirely sure how Netrender works, but come to think of it the `client` might actually provide the needed data..