# problem with network render and fluid simulation

Tags: rendering, fluid-simulation, network

I have a problem:i want to render a fluid simulation animation ( with pictures) using my ubuntu server with network render, but when after i launch it, i have some images but it seems like my server didnt bake it and render it at the same time.
Can someone help me?

thx for your future help ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use baked fluid with network render?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5262/how-to-use-baked-fluid-with-network-render)

Comment: yeah i've seen this post before but the problem is i don't want to set manually the render for all slaves, i just want to connect my slaves and my client to the master and run the render :/

Comment: Maybe blender can't do it now, in another versioin maybe